# Bot doesn't edit role permissions for each channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make an anti-spam and when the bot is supposed to edit the muted role's permission for each channel nothing happens.

So first I create the role

```js
const mute_role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Muted");
  if (!mute_role) {
    try {
      mute_role = await message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
          name: "Muted",
          color: "#000000",
          permissions: []
        }
      })
```

Then i edit the role's permissions on all guild's channels

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.updateOverwrite(mute_role, 
          {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          }
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }
```

And after doing this it should continue to the rest of the code but it seems to skip that part because it continues to the anti-spam and adds the role if spam is triggered

Here is the full code for the anti-spam

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const mute_role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Muted");
  if (!mute_role) {
    try {
      mute_role = await message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
          name: "Muted",
          color: "#000000",
          permissions: []
        }
      })
      message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.updateOverwrite(mute_role, 
          {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          }
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }
  if (usersMap.has(message.author.id)) {
    const userData = usersMap.get(message.author.id);
    const { lastMessage, timer } = userData;
    const difference = message.createdTimestamp - lastMessage.createdTimestamp;
    let msgCount = userData.msgCount;
    console.log(difference);

    if (difference > DIFF) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      console.log('Cleared timeout');
      userData.msgCount = 1;
      userData.lastMessage = message;
      userData.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        usersMap.delete(message.author.id);
        console.log('Removed from RESET');
      }, TIME);
      usersMap.set(message.author.id, userData);
    }
    else {
      msgCount++;
      console.log(msgCount)
      if (parseInt(msgCount) === LIMIT) {
        message.member.roles.add(mute_role);
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} has been muted for spamming`);
        setTimeout(() => {
          message.member.roles.remove(mute_role);
          message.channel.send(`${message.author} has been unmuted`);
        }, TIME);
      }
      else {
        userData.msgCount = msgCount;
        usersMap.set(message.author.id, userData);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    let fn = setTimeout(() => {
      usersMap.delete(message.author.id);
      console.log('Removed from map');
    }, TIME);
    usersMap.set(message.author.id, {
      msgCount: 1,
      lastMessage: message,
      timer: fn
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I just found out why it was not working

Instead of using

```
const mute_role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Muted");
```

I just had to use

```
let mute_role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Muted");
```

Now it works and overwrites the channels permissions[image]

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer and close your question so others who might have the same problem can find the right solution easier.